# PHP Array with Multidimensional Array – UNIQUE

Tags: php, database

There are 4500 multidimensional arrays inside an array. Need to filter for uniqueness them on all keys (date, portfolio_ID, summ, value), but except **[id] => value** because **id** always unique and then return to the final array. Please tell me how to do this with minimal load?

✓ – duplicates

Input

```
$array = [
    4482 => [
        "id"           => "4597608",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05", ✓
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",      ✓
        "summ"         => "597199",     ✓
        "value"        => "RUR"         ✓
    ],
    4483 => [
        "id"           => "4597609",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05",
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",
        "summ"         => "597199",
        "value"        => "summ"
    ],
    4484 => [
        "id"           => "4597611",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05", ✓
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",      ✓
        "summ"         => "597199",     ✓
        "value"        => "RUR"         ✓
    ],
    4485 => [
        "id"           => "4597608",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05", ✓
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",      ✓
        "summ"         => "5954769"
        "value"        => "RUR"         ✓
    ],
    4486 => [
        "id"           => "4597611",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05", ✓
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",      ✓
        "summ"         => "598655",     
        "value"        => "EUR"         
    ]
];
```

Output

```
$array = [
    4482 => [
        "id"           => "4597608",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05",
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",
        "summ"         => "597199",
        "value"        => "RUR"
    ],
    4483 => [
        "id"           => "4597609",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05",
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",
        "summ"         => "597199",
        "value"        => "summ"
    ],
    4485 => [
        "id"           => "4597608",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05",
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",
        "summ"         => "5954769"
        "value"        => "RUR"
    ],
    4486 => [
        "id"           => "4597611",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05",
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",
        "summ"         => "598655",     
        "value"        => "EUR"         
    ]
];
```

Comment: What do you mean "filter them"? Based on what? You just removed the last entry. Also please share your own attempts/ideas.

Comment: @Jeto
I need to get only unique values, but ['id'] key is always unique and filtering arrays does not make sense with it. First hide it, get unique values and then put it back

Comment: description fixed

Comment: Is the key of any use? The 4483? Can I change it or do you need it?

Comment: 4483 not need. Can change

Comment: the item with key 4482 and 4485 has the same id. why are they in the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the array then loop it.
In the loop create a new array with key being all the data that you want to filter on.
Because keys must be unique the array will be filtered.

I remove the associative keys just to make the array "nicely looking".

```
$arr = array_reverse($arr);

foreach($arr as $sub){
    $new[$sub['date'].$sub['portfolio_ID'].$sub['summ'].$sub['value']] = $sub;
}
$new = array_values($new);

var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/CKILH

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need. Maybe you could tell me how to unify code for other tables where keys names can be any, but there is always ['id'] or ['ID'] that need also throw away

Comment: @RE something like this? https://3v4l.org/iVpNF it implodes all values then removes the id. I'm not very proud of this method, I believe it can break quite easily

Comment: Possibly a better method. https://3v4l.org/s0ktA make a copy and unset ID, then use the copy as the key of the next array

Answer (score 0):

Just use array_filter

```
$array = [
    4482 => [
        "id"           => "4597608",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05",
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",
        "summ"         => "597199",
        "value"        => "RUR"
    ],
    4483 => [
        "id"           => "4597609",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05",
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",
        "summ"         => "597199",
        "value"        => "summ"
    ],
    4484 => [
        "id"          => "4597611",
        "date"         => "2020-03-05",
        "portfolio_ID" => "21177",
        "summ"         => "597199",
        "value"        => "RUR"
    ]
];

$result=[];
array_walk($array, function($item, $key) use(&$result){
    if(count(array_filter($result,function($already_added) use(&$result, $item){
        return $already_added['date']==$item['date'] &&
               $already_added['portfolio_ID']==$item['portfolio_ID'] &&
               $already_added['summ']==$item['summ'] &&
               $already_added['value']==$item['value'];
    }))==0) $result[$key]=$item;
});

var_dump($result);
```

The example above will dump:

```
array (size=2)
  4482 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '4597608' (length=7)
      'date' => string '2020-03-05' (length=10)
      'portfolio_ID' => string '21177' (length=5)
      'summ' => string '597199' (length=6)
      'value' => string 'RUR' (length=3)
  4483 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '4597609' (length=7)
      'date' => string '2020-03-05' (length=10)
      'portfolio_ID' => string '21177' (length=5)
      'summ' => string '597199' (length=6)
      'value' => string 'summ' (length=4)
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I need
I need to check arrays for uniqueness on all keys except id